# Somar colunas Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Eu preciso somar as duas colunas quando uma delas for alterada, por exemplo: se avaliação for alterado a maior nota fica em nota final, a mesma coisa para estudos orientados.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    tablenotas: [
       {
          avaliacao: 1,
          estudos_orientados: 2,
          nota_final: 3,
      }, 
       {
          avaliacao: 4,
          estudos_orientados: 5,
          nota_final: 9,
    }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
  nota: function (avaliacao, estudos_orientados) {
    if (avaliacao >= estudos_orientados) {
      return avaliacao
    }
    else if (estudos_orientados > avaliacao) {
      return estudos_orientados
    }
  }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
  <table>
  <thead>
    <th>Avaliação</th>
    <th>Estudos Orientados</th>
    <th>Nota Final</th>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in tablenotas">
        <td><input type="text" v-model="item.avaliacao"></td>
        <td><input type="text" v-model="item.estudos_orientados"></td>
        <td><input type="text">{{nota(item.avaliacao, item.estudos_orientados)}}</td>

      </tr>


    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Também coloquei no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luissouza/7ft73q85/)

Comment: O que deseja é somar e adicionar esse valor em `nota_final` ? Ou que o valor de `{{nota(item.avaliacao, item.estudos_orientados)}}` fique no campo?

Comment: @NoobSaibot Eu preciso dos dois. Mostrar o valor e alterar o valor de nota_final

Comment: Certo, deixei uma resposta. Mas o correto não seria exibir a soma das notas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que na sua resposta o problema é que você está utilizando a interpolação, e como está utilizando um `<input>` dentro da `<td>`, pode-se utilizar um `v-bind:value` ou apenas `:value` para realizar um `bind` do valor que está sendo retornado do método ao `input`.

Outro ponto é que modifiquei o método utilizando algo que, não tenho certeza da nomenclatura correta mas creio que o nome é *early return*, onde você evita trabalhar com *else*, e sim priorizando o *return*.

Verifique no exemplo abaixo:

**EDIT:** Faltou colocar os `parseInt` na comparação da nota, logo estava ocorrendo problemas em conversão de *string* para *integer*.

**EDIT#2:** Adicionado validações para em casos de apagar todo o campo e o mesmo ficar vazio. Neste caso mostrará no último campo o que estiver preenchido. Se ambos estiverem vazios colocará 0.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    tablenotas: [
       {
          avaliacao: 1,
          estudos_orientados: 2,
          nota_final: 3,
      }, 
       {
          avaliacao: 4,
          estudos_orientados: 5,
          nota_final: 9,
    }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    nota (avaliacao, estudos_orientados) {
      if ((avaliacao !== '') && (estudos_orientados !== '')) {
      
        if (parseInt(avaliacao) > parseInt(estudos_orientados)) {
          return avaliacao
        }      

        return estudos_orientados
      }
      
      if (avaliacao === '') {
        if (estudos_orientados === '') {
          return 0
        }
        
        return estudos_orientados
      }
      
      return avaliacao
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
  <table>
  <thead>
    <th>Avaliação</th>
    <th>Estudos Orientados</th>
    <th>Nota Final</th>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in tablenotas">
        <td><input type="text" v-model="item.avaliacao"></td>
        <td><input type="text" v-model="item.estudos_orientados"></td>
        <td><input type="text" :value="nota(item.avaliacao, item.estudos_orientados)"></td>

      </tr>


    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Tem horas que funciona, tem horas que não. Por exemplo: se você coloca 10 na avaliação e depois 99 nos estudos orientados, funciona. Mas, se você voltar e colocar 100 na avaliação ele não calcula mais. Em vários testes ele para de funcionar

Comment: Desculpa, não reparei nisto, vou ver aqui.

Comment: @LuisSouza Editei a resposta

Comment: As duas respostas estão funcionando. Como eu seleciono?

Comment: Está funcionando, mas, tem um porém. Se uma nota for em branco ou 0 não funciona.

Comment: Nem sempre os dois valores serão preenchidos.As vezes apenas um, então ele será o maior

Comment: Entendi, não me liguei neste detalhe também. Veja se as validações que fiz são o suficiente.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do *guastallaigor*, seu código tem um problema, ao editar os campos os valores são convertidos para *string*, o que acaba fazendo seu código parar de funcionar.

Então recomendo converter para inteiro antes de verificar qual é maior.

```
avaliacao = parseInt(avaliacao);
estudos_orientados = parseInt(estudos_orientados);
```

Mas eu faria o seguinte, em vez de passar como parâmetro as propriedades `item.avaliacao` e `item.estudos_orientados` eu passaria apenas o índice, para isso tem que modificar o atributo `v-for` para:

```
v-for="(item, index) in tablenotas"
```

e no template o campo:

```
<input type="text" :value="nota(index)">
```

o método, ficaria assim:

```
nota(index) {
  // parseInt converte a string para inteiro
  var avaliacao = parseInt(this.tablenotas[index].avaliacao),
      estudos_orientados = parseInt(this.tablenotas[index].estudos_orientados);
  if (!avaliacao) avaliacao = 0;
  if (!estudos_orientados) estudos_orientados = 0;
  // Abaixo é feita a soma e atribuido a propriedade "nota_final" do
  // índice "index"
  this.tablenotas[index].nota_final = avaliacao + estudos_orientados;
  return (avaliacao >= estudos_orientados) ? avaliacao : estudos_orientados;
}
```

#### Veja funcionando:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    tablenotas: [
      {
        avaliacao: 1,
        estudos_orientados: 2,
        nota_final: 3,
      }, 
      {
        avaliacao: 4,
        estudos_orientados: 5,
        nota_final: 9,
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    nota(index) {
      // parseInt converte a string para inteiro
      var avaliacao = parseInt(this.tablenotas[index].avaliacao),
          estudos_orientados = parseInt(this.tablenotas[index].estudos_orientados);
      if (!avaliacao) avaliacao = 0;
      if (!estudos_orientados) estudos_orientados = 0;
      // Abaixo é feita a soma e atribuido a propriedade "nota_final" do
      // índice "index"
      this.tablenotas[index].nota_final = avaliacao + estudos_orientados;
      return (avaliacao >= estudos_orientados) ? avaliacao : estudos_orientados;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Avaliação</th>
      <th>Estudos Orientados</th>
      <th>Nota Final</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item, index) in tablenotas">
        <td><input type="text" v-model="item.avaliacao"></td>
        <td><input type="text" v-model="item.estudos_orientados"></td>
        <td><input type="text" :value="nota(index)"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Está funcionando, mas, tem um porém. Se uma nota for em branco ou 0 não funciona.

Comment: @LuisSouza veja agora, pra mim só não estava funcionando quando o campo estava vazio, já colocando o zero em qualquer um funciona perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

Podes simplificar isso e usar o `Math.max`assim:

```
methods: {
    nota: function() {
        return Math.max(...arguments);
    }
}
```

dessa maneira não ficas preso a somente 2 valores. Podias ainda fazer uma nova array no `computed` e adicionar-lhe as notas já calculadas, a melhor solução depende do que procuras fazer com os dados depois.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    tablenotas: [{
        avaliacao: 1,
        estudos_orientados: 2,
        nota_final: 3,
      },
      {
        avaliacao: 4,
        estudos_orientados: 5,
        nota_final: 9,
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    nota: function() {
      return Math.max(...arguments);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #ccc;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Avaliação</th>
      <th>Estudos Orientados</th>
      <th>Nota Final</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in tablenotas">
        <td><input type="text" v-model="item.avaliacao"></td>
        <td><input type="text" v-model="item.estudos_orientados"></td>
        <td><input type="text" readonly :value="nota(item.avaliacao, item.estudos_orientados)"></td>

      </tr>


    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```